# Buttons above Recycler View in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

In my project, I have RecyclerView and trying to display items using RecycleView. Everything is working fine but button in the below code is not showing the the first recyclerview item and hiding it. Any help is appreciated.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="TestFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/testrv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="563dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/next_prev_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rv_homepost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="Previous" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An advice first - it's not a good approach to define a specific size for a recycler view - this depends on device resolution/ dimensions and might not work on all. What I typically due is to re-arrange it between the layout views in order to fit it between the available space.*

I'm not sure if I've understood the problem correctly - but by seeing the result of your code on Android Studio I believe it's the buttons that are overlapped with the recycler view, right?

Suggestion:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/next_prev_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/testrv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```